# How to set default value for TextInputLayout in Android

Tags: java, android, material-design

I'm using the `TextInputLayout` [from Google's Material Design](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/) on Android. I want to set the default text value for the text field.

I know I can set the hint, helper text, and error message, but I want to programatically set the default text value that in other cases would eventually be input by the user.

According to the docs you can technically switch the inner `TextInputEditText` to a regular `EditText` but Google does not recommend doing this. Should I explore the risks of doing that or is there a built-in solution I'm missing?

Comment: It's not clear what the confusion is, but you set text on a `TextInputEditText` just like you would a regular `EditText`: with the `android:text` attribute in XML, or the `setText()` method in code.

Comment: @MikeM. the confusion arose from the fact that the [developer.google.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout) documentation as well as the [material.io](https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/) documentation did not mention the android:text attribute for the wrapper element or inner `TextInputEditText`, Android Studio did not offer it as an autocomplete suggestion, and typing the attribute in manually [caused a weird preview rendering issue](https://imgur.com/beKJafk). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use`setText` method for **TextInputEditTest** as below where ever you want :

```
textInputEditText.setText(R.string.yourStringName);//string from resources
textInputEditText.setText("yourString");//static string
```

If you want to set default text when your **activity** or **fragment** initialize You should use setText in **onCreate** method which is the first callback in activity and fragment life cycle.

And the last thing : you can set default text for **TextInputEditText** not **TextInputLayout** because TextInputLayout extends from LinearLayout and therefore it doesn't have text property.

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because the docs didn't mention setText or the android:text attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your use case is, but you may think of one of the following:

Case 1: You want the user to see the default text

1. Write your default text in the hint field.
2. When it's time for the app to collect the data, if the View has no text, then use the default text.

Case 2: User doesn't need to see the default text

1. Keep your hint text as you have it now.
2. When it's time for the app to collect the data, if the View has no text, then use the default text.

If either of these cases don't work for you, please clarify the user experience you are seeking. E.g., do you want to wait after a certain event/time to switch the hint with a default text?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Turns out you can use the `android:text` attribute and `setText()` on the inner `TextInputEditText` element, it just isn't mentioned in the docs or suggested by Android Studio.